# How to add page the same slug like custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

Hi we have the custom post type:

```
$labels = array(
    'name' => __( 'Recipes' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'Recetas' ),
    'add_new' => __( 'New Receta' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Receta' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit  Receta' ),
    'new_item' => __( 'New Receta' ),
    'view_item' => __( 'View Receta' ),
    'search_items' => __( 'Find Receta' ),
    'not_found' =>  __( 'Nothing found' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No items found in trash.' ),
    
);

$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'custom-fields',
        'thumbnail'
    ),
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-list-view'
);
register_post_type( 'recetas', $args );
```

But we don't need an archive page for this post type. We have created a page for this porpose. The problem is that we can't have this page have a slug: /recetas/ despite the fact that in the arguments of the custom post noted: 'has_archive' => false I know that the archive page has higher priority. But is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings -> Permalinks and that should flush permalinks. WordPress needs to regenerate permastructs each time you made a modification, one way to do that is by that menu page, another - programmatically, via function [flush_rewrite_rules()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/) (just remember to remove it afterwards, cause it's a time-consuming process).